# Vim background with gnu screen

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen

I am having trouble with my colorscheme in `vim`. When editing a file using a vim session started in GNU screen, the text background is not rendered correctly. In a session outside screen, the entire background is gray (how it should be). For a vim window inside screen, only the background directly behind the text appears gray. The rest is black.

I have TERM set to `xterm-256color` in both my `.cshrc` and `.screenrc`. My `.vimrc` has `set t_Co=256`

I am using `csh`.

Edit: I am connecting through `cygwin`.

Comment: 1st of all, you are not working on tty, are u? then you could try if `term screen-256color` in your screenrc works

Comment: I did try that as well - no luck.

Comment: setenv TERM xterm-256color

Comment: To enable colors on XTerm you will need to run the configure scripts with the --enable-256-color switch

Comment: My xterm is working perfectly - but screen is displaying background color in vim slightly wrong. I already have `setenv TERM xterm-256color`

Comment: I found the issue, I needed to have this set:

defbce "on"

This forces background colours to refresh.

"Change background-color-erase setting. If bce is set to “on”, all characters cleared by an erase/insert/scroll/clear operation will be displayed in the current background color. Otherwise the default background color is used."

Comment: Ravi, please write that as an answer; it's difficult to find otherwise.

Comment: I intended to come back and fill it in today - I was unable to post answers yesterday since my account was new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[filling in for the OP, see the comment]

The OP found the issue:

> I needed to have this set:
>
> ```
> defbce "on"
> ```
>
> This forces background colours to refresh.
>
> > "Change background-color-erase setting. If `bce` is set to “on”, all characters cleared by an erase/insert/scroll/clear operation will be displayed in the current background color. Otherwise the default background color is used."
>
> – Ravi 19 hours ago

Answer (score 9):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that color schemes work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.

Answer (score 5):

To make vim, bash, and screen settings work together:

1) In .bashrc add the following:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

2) In .screenrc add the following:

```
altscreen on
defbce on
set term=screen-256color
```